# How to avoid duplicate records in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, duplicates

I have two tables. Both have purchase order information coming in from two different sources.

`DBO.PO1` has PO_Number, PO_Descripion, VendorCode, VendorName and stores about 90,000 rows.

`DBO.PO2` has VendorCode, VendorName, VendorAddress and holds about 25,000 rows.

Now I need to join these two tables and populate another table say, `DBO.PO3`. This table should have all the unique columns from `DBO.PO1` and `DBO.PO2`.

```
SELECT COUNT(1) 
FROM DBO.PO1 
WHERE ISNULL(LTRIM(RTRIM(VendorCode)),'') IN (SELECT DISTINCT VendorCode 
                                              FROM DBO.PO2 
                                              WHERE ISNULL(LTRIM(RTRIM(VendorCode)), '') <> '') --returns 45,000 rows
```

I tried the regular inner join

```
SELECT a.*, b.VendorAddress 
FROM DBO.PO1 a 
INNER JOIN DBO.PO2 b ON ISNULL(LTRIM(RTRIM(a.VendorCode)), '') = ISNULL(LTRIM(RTRIM(b.VendorCode)), '')
WHERE ISNULL(LTRIM(RTRIM(a.VendorCode)), '') <> ''
```

This is fetching me somewhere around 600,000 records. I thought I was missing out the distinct combination so I tried even the below method.

```
  SELECT a.*, b.VendorAddress 
  FROM DBO.PO1 a 
  INNER JOIN 
      (SELECT DISTINCT VendorCode,VendorAddress FROM DBO.PO2) b 
           ON ISNULL(LTRIM(RTRIM(a.VendorCode)), '') = ISNULL(LTRIM(RTRIM(b.VendorCode)), '')
  WHERE ISNULL(LTRIM(RTRIM(a.VendorCode)), '') <> ''
```

I'm still getting several duplicates. I tried even the Union but the result set is the same.

My result set should have those 45,000 records with the unique columns from both these tables.

Comment: Posting the table definitions and some sample data would help clarify things problem and help encourage others to answer.  See [How to Create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Also, feel free to use collaborative tools like http://sqlfiddle.com/ or https://dbfiddle.uk/ which are great for sharing schemas.

Comment: If your tables have about 90k and 25k rows and your join query produces 600k rows, then that suggests two things. First is that your join logic is faulty. Second is that your tables might not represent what you think. In PO2, how many distinct values for VendorCode exist. If that number is not 25k (same as total rows), then you have a data problem at least. Apply that same logic to PO1. PO_Number.  I'm guessing that you have duplicate rows (as far as the key columns are concerned) in both tables.

Comment: The problem is the `ON` condition is matching more than one record. You need the `ON` conditions to be specific enough that **exactly** one record is matched from both sides.

Comment: It's like it's trying to join the NULL's also? Maybe you meant `ON NULLIF(LTRIM(RTRIM(a.VendorCode)), '') = NULLIF(LTRIM(RTRIM(b.VendorCode)), '')`?

Comment: First, your inner join will not get unique records from both tables. it will just get you common records based on the join condition. 
For unique records from both tables either you should insert them separately, or use full outer joins. The query may vary based on the data. Now based on your join condition if there are 100 records with 'V1' vendor code in DBO.PO1 and 50 records in DBO.PO2, your result will be 100*50 = 5000 records. definitely, the Vendor code is not the correct join condition.

Comment: If you think you have all purchase records in the first table, you should use LEFT join in your second query, and duplicate rows in your second query must be because of the Same vendor having a different address.

Comment: Hi All. Thank you for all your replies, got much more insight into the data. It so happens PurchaseOrder Number and Purshase Order Doc date combination is the only unique combination available to join these two tables and it worked

Answer (score 1):

You should first get all vendor codes and see which exists in which table:

```
select J.VendorCode, p1.PO_Number, p1.PO_Descripion, p2.VendorAddress from (
    select VendorCode from DBO.PO1
    union
    select VendorCode from DBO.PO2
) J
left join DBO.PO1 p1 on ISNULL(LTRIM(RTRIM(p1.VendorCode)), '') = ISNULL(LTRIM(RTRIM(J.VendorCode)), '')
left join DBO.PO2 p2 on ISNULL(LTRIM(RTRIM(p2.VendorCode)), '') = ISNULL(LTRIM(RTRIM(J.VendorCode)), '')
```

Comment: Hi Mert Ulkgun. Thank you for you reply, got much more insight into the data. It so happens PurchaseOrder Number and Purshase Order Doc date combination is the only unique combination available to join these two tables.  Your reply is also certainly useful.